# Need algorithm to generate color codes

Tags: algorithm, colors

I see many questions asking for help with an algorithm, so I'm hoping this is a reasonable question for the site.

I'm developing a product with Python to chart part histories in a machine. There are three of the same type of part in a machine at any given time, and each part has a 3-digit serial number. These parts are often swapped around or replaced with another part with a different 3-digit serial number. I want engineers and maintenance personnel to be able to visualize a part being swapped around or replaced. I thought this could be done with varying background colors, but if anyone has a better idea I'm very much open to suggestions.

I tried a number of different permutations, plugging the 3 digits into an RGB color chart, multiplying the digits, placing each digit in a different place in the RGB code, reversing the numbers, etc., but the numbers often vary by a single digit, and everything I've tried results in colors too difficult to differentiate.

To date, most of the serial numbers are within the range of 600 to 800, but this isn't guaranteed. The sample data I have at the moment has numbers ranging from 724 to 784.

Of course, any suggestions don't have to be *in* Python, just as long as I can eventually translate it *into* Python.

Comment: Try using a hashing function to convert the serial number to something more random.

Comment: instead of mapping a serial number to color you can just keep a pool of colors (visually distinct) and assign a new one when a new thing comes in or is being replaced

Comment: If you need to distinguish many items, you should use other visual means in addition to color (or rather than color) to distinguish them. For example, you can identify the parts with letters or numbers, or use different shapes, different shading, different dash patterns, etc.  It may be hard to distinguish more than 22 colors without other cues (see, for example, the 22 maximum-contrast colors of Kelly, 1965).

Comment: Using S/N or hash directly as color is not a good idea as it might conflict your color scheme  instead I would: 1. create list of usable colors (ideally power of 2 number of colors) in your product color scheme 2. from serial number create a hash that will be used as index for the color table, you can use any hash like SHA or MD5 or CRC32 and use just lover bits tomap into your color table.

Comment: All good answers that I'll play with, still remains to be seen how adjacent cells can be viewed and still not blow out the user's eyes ;-) I even considered different levels of grey, but looking at colors in an RGB tool and in a table of data are very different things. Thanks everyone!